# tensorflow distributed async training: two workers print out log for same global step

Tags: tensorflow

I am following this link to create distributed asynchronized multi-gpu training
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py

every 10 training steps I printed out training log with loss value, global step value, etc. However I found out in the log that sometimes two workers print out the same global step (as can be seen from below log), I did not expect this to happen.

```
expr_dist_async_b32.worker1.log:2018-06-12 00:09:59 Worker 1: step 13 (global step 50), sample prob 0.100000, train loss = 3.033742, lrate=0.000107, norm=1.311264
expr_dist_async_b32.worker2.log:2018-06-12 00:09:59 Worker 2: step 13 (global step 50), sample prob 0.100000, train loss = 3.060724, lrate=0.000107, norm=1.311264
expr_dist_async_b32.worker3.log:2018-06-12 00:10:08 Worker 3: step 16 (global step 60), sample prob 0.100000, train loss = 2.913497, lrate=0.000108, norm=1.034301
expr_dist_async_b32.worker2.log:2018-06-12 00:10:15 Worker 2: step 18 (global step 70), sample prob 0.100000, train loss = 2.913340, lrate=0.000109, norm=0.895563
expr_dist_async_b32.worker3.log:2018-06-12 00:10:25 Worker 3: step 21 (global step 80), sample prob 0.100000, train loss = 2.924278, lrate=0.000111, norm=1.006683
```

anyone know why this happened?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following happens in this example.

The `global_step` variable is created on the parameter server. Each worker when it starts, get it along with all the other variables. Each worker has an optimizer that, when run, computes the gradients and the increment of the global step. The gradients and the increment operation are sent to the parameter server. These operations are executed on the ps and the worker gets the resulting values.

In this setup, if you don't choose synchronous training, you can see pretty much anything on the workers. If two workers send their updates at the same time, they can both get back the same resulting value of the `global_step`.